# Automatically infer output type from input type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

How would I infer output of a simple array helper function based on the input element type of the array? I don't want to have to use generics at the point of use, as this overly complicates the code.

The below code is a simple helper function that ensures an array is returned, either the one passed or an empty one. This helps reason with possible `undefined` values that are assumed to be arrays:

```js
export const ensureArray = (arr?: unknown[]): unknown[] => (arr || [])
```

This seems pretty basic but I'm having trouble implementing this generically. I don't want to have to declare the type at the point of use, á la:

```js
export const ensureArray = <T>(arr?: T[]): T[] => (arr || [])

ensureArray<string>(possiblyUndefinedArrayOfStrings)
```

As the above is harder to maintain. I just want to have the code infer the type based on what is passed (as this has already been defined before it is passed).

Comment: Can you check if this is the solution that you are looking for? [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOln7N)

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Right now it's pseudocode or a typo (you haven't declared the `T` type anywhere) and is missing relevant declarations (what is `possiblyUndefinedArrayOfStrings`? Presumably it's of type `string[] | undefined`, but if I declare a variable of that type and pass it to a generic `ensureArray` then `string[]` comes out. If you have code where that doesn't work, it would be a big help if you showed it). Ideally example code is something others can just paste into an IDE to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach actually works, the "problem" is that TypeScript is smart enough to figure that in certain scenarios your input is *always* undefined thus it cannot infer an array type from `undefined`.

```
export const ensureArray = <T,>(arr?: T[]): T[] => arr ?? [];

/* UNKNOWN VALUES */
declare var unknownArr1: undefined | string[];
declare var unknownArr2: undefined | number[];

const arr1 =
//    ^? const arr1: string[]
ensureArray(unknownArr1);
//          ^? var unknownArr1: string[] | undefined
//          TS does not know if it's string[] or undefined, string is inferred

const arr2 = ensureArray(unknownArr2);
//    ^? const arr2: number[]

/* KNOWN VALUES */
let knownArr1: undefined | string[] = undefined;
let knownArr2: undefined | number[] = [];


const knownArr1ensured =
//    ^? const knownArr1ensured: unknown[]
ensureArray(knownArr1);
//          ^? let knownArr1: undefined
//          TS knows this is always "undefined" thus undefined is inferred

const knownArr2ensured = ensureArray(knownArr2);
//    ^? const knownArr2ensured: number[]
```

Here's an [interactive plaground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72GgrlYBBKKAQwE84BeOAHgBUAaAPgAojCB+ALjhoG0BdAJRdefCgzisocNmzj8A3AChlAegBUcAKoA5ANLaA8gHVtcAGp4AMpoCiAZThqVigCbAEAG1bA4AN1ZwWMgA1sgQAO7IBFAAjFxBbgBmAJbIwC5wAD5w6FCpAOYKru5euH4BQaERUYQATPHISanpWXDIWAC2AEbAUEXKSGjwkjEUiioqcFNwAHpsipioOPiEpEyVYZHRMQJKE9MH03Pjk4cHNA4uEMCobRDwVeFwyYnPMADkt7kF-HDQgY1gCk0i46DkYHlkPlnrdUolergXAMUOgJHUKHBFstomsNtVorVdicDsdlOMNPpjKYLNZ7I5nB5gA9NjVYg0miDWt8ob9KAkgc0XEpGcz8XV2QLOdl2t1ery5HwlMihnBHqyYljEWN9kd5pqVsQSEw1dsiTqzlNjuaLRdVZtbjAABbJWG3IgecKkW4AIn5wPS3rgTqwtz9gphz2Q8MI6WVqJNdX1GUo+pxRoTUEJe1OlvmQA). It shows how when the values are known to TypeScript it cannot infer however, when they are not known for certain, the union type cannot be resolved and can therefore be inferred.